# How to configure a PHP website on IIS?

Tags: php, iis

I want to configure a PHP website on IIS. I have XAMPP installed on the Windows Server-2012 and my PHP pages run absolutely fine through XAMPP.
I want to run my site through IIS.

So,first i have tried to run a simple test.html file by putting it into C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.html it is running absolutely fine.Now if i am trying to run a simple test.php file i got the same page from .html file.so,Basicaly what I need to know is how to run a .php file through IIS as a website.

NOTE-

- Php is installed with XAMPP on D:\xampp\php
- IIS 6.0 is installed

Do I need to install something else to make my php pages run though IIS?
I am new to PHP and IIS, so any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: You might run PHP Diagnostics to see if you missed anything, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/php-diagnostics.html

Comment: Hello, did you get a solution to this problem you share, please?